# Changing Image on selected state of UITablView cell

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a created a custom cell and added one label and Image, I have 4 rows in my table each row has a different image and each row opens a different view controller, so, now what I need is on click of a particular row I want the image to change to do that I tried this, but its not working, so please help me out.

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{

     if(cell.selected == true)
     {
           UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];        
           cell.icon.image    = cellImage;
      }
      else
      {
          UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];        
           cell.icon.image    = cellImage;
      }
}
```

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do following when creating your cell or in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
```

It will work for your `icon` property too if it is `UIImageView`

Comment: hey andriy , thanks for replying, I tried it but its not working

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Nothing changed or just wrong result?

Comment: On click , the image did not change, the image is same as before click

Comment: Maybe its because you use same image "abc.png" :)

Answer (score 2):

First create a property in your custom cell for uiImageview and synthesize it..

and the in didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method of UITabeView access the property and change the image something like :-

```
yourCell.yourImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]
```

For Sample I am giving my Code :-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomizedCellProductDetails : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *sNO;
    UILabel *abcWine;
    UILabel *redWine;
    UILabel *two;
    UILabel *hundred;
    UILabel *fourTwo;
    UILabel *twoOne;
    UIImageView *imgView;

    UILabel *itemNo;
    UILabel *itemName;
    UILabel *itemDesc;
    UILabel *department;
    UILabel *qtyAvailable;

    UIButton *check;

}

@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *sNO;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *abcWine;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *redWine;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *two;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *hundred;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *fourTwo;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *twoOne;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UIImageView *imgView;

@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *itemNo;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *itemName;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *itemDesc;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *department;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *qtyAvailable;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UIButton *check;

-(void) clicked;
@end
```

.m file synthesize it:-

```
#import "CustomizedCellProductDetails.h"


@implementation CustomizedCellProductDetails
@synthesize sNO,abcWine,redWine,two,hundred,fourTwo,twoOne,imgView,itemNo,itemName,itemDesc,department,qtyAvailable,check;
```

in tableview delegate :-

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
    <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
    */
CustomizedCellProductDetails * cell = (CustomizedCellProductDetails )[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
[cell.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wine.png"]];

    }
```

Comment: I know that, I want to know how to set a different image on click of cell

Comment: thats what i told on click didselectrow at indexpath will be called access the property and change the image

Comment: ok roronoa,I got your point, I will check that and get back to u

Comment: Hey, its working, the image changes on click, but when I return back the image is still the clicked Image. but need the unclicked Image when I return back

Comment: Hey , please help me out, selected image stays their and I am not able to remove it when I come back from detailview

Comment: if u return back via nav change the image in viewDidAppear or selector back button of your back button or tell me the flow of returning back

Comment: i return back through nav bar back button, and please let me know how should I change the image in viewDidAppear

Comment: you will have to store the uitableviewcell , your custom cell class's object locally or say in appdelegate creating its property and then access the same object to change its image through customclass's property in viewdidAppear or better have it in back button selector.

Comment: hey I have 4 rows, in my table and each row as a different image,so dont u think, I should get the index of the row and then change the image, something like this [tableview indexpathofselectedrow];

Comment: At didselectrowatindexpath the cell is clicked and image is changed so you tore that cell as it has all the information as object ans yes you have to extract the cell using indexpath.....indexpath is simply in delegate method parameters.

Comment: YourCustomCell *getChangedCell=(yourCustomCell *)[tableview cellforrowatindexpath] to get the cell.

Comment: you mean to say i should use this function in viewdidAppear?

Comment: no get this cell and store it in appdelegata and then on viewDidAppear acces it from there and change its via accesing its property

Comment: One simple thing here is that you want the table to be in default state on back press so just reload the table and nothing else to do :)

Comment: hey thanks, this is the best solution, and its works like charm...no need to change anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following when creating your cell ...

In Implementation Block...

```
@implementation ABC
{
    NSMutableArray  *imageArray;
    NSMutableArray  *imageSelectedArray;
}
```

Do this In the below method

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    [cell.imageView setHighlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageSelectedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
}
```