# Edit the Uitableviewcell Content by User

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I would like to get you help on the below things.

I have a uitableview list which has contents fetched from DB.
Now i would like to edit the tableviewcell content there itself.

I mean how to allow the uitableviewcells editable?

Please let me know the working sample link / reference tutorial to implement the above things.

Thanks for your time.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *aDict = [self.mySimpleTemplatesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *value = [aDict objectForKey:@"value"];
    cell.textLabel.text = value;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you want to edit the data of  UITableview?

Comment: yes i want to edit the data of uitableviewcell content

Comment: edit the db values and reload the rows that are updated or just reload the tableview

Comment: what i am asking is how to edit the content in tableviewcell ( like placing the uitextfield) etc

Comment: hello wait i will create the demo like you want and gives the refrence link to you

Answer (score 0):

I create the sample code for the when selecting the cell item then i displays the model popup and then that item is update and then press to update then that item update and shows into the table,

I think it's the simple and easily to use into application and firing the operation of the database also.

so you can download the sample code from here.

i hope you can easily understan and implement that code into your project thus problem may be solved

Please Download the source which developed by me for sample code also you can more enhance this code.

[Download Link Here.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Student%20Database/StudentInfoDatabase.zip/download)

Comment: thanks for the reply, currently i am doing the same thing as you have told.navigating to new page when editing.can you please show me how to edit it on the list itself rather than going to new page.pls let me know and thanks

Comment: so you need to implement the custom cell

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample ,It's one of my codes .:-

```
@interface CustomizedCellProductDetails : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *sNO;
    UILabel *abcWine;
    UILabel *redWine;
    UILabel *two;
    UILabel *hundred;
    UILabel *fourTwo;
    UILabel *twoOne;
    UIImageView *imgView;

    UILabel *itemNo;
    UILabel *itemName;
    UILabel *itemDesc;
    UILabel *department;
    UILabel *qtyAvailable;

    UIButton *check;

}

@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *sNO;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *abcWine;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *redWine;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *two;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *hundred;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *fourTwo;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *twoOne;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UIImageView *imgView;

@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *itemNo;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *itemName;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *itemDesc;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *department;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UILabel *qtyAvailable;
@property (nonatomic , retain) UIButton *check;

-(void) clicked;
@end
```

## import "CustomizedCellProductDetails.h"

```
@implementation CustomizedCellProductDetails
@synthesize sNO,abcWine,redWine,two,hundred,fourTwo,twoOne,imgView,itemNo,itemName,itemDesc,department,qtyAvailable,check;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        sNO=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        abcWine=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        redWine=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        two=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        hundred=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        fourTwo=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        twoOne=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];

        itemNo=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        itemName=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        itemDesc=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        department=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        qtyAvailable=[[UILabel alloc] init];

        check=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [check addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [check setTitle:@"Check" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.contentView addSubview:sNO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:abcWine];
        [self.contentView addSubview:redWine];
        [self.contentView addSubview:two];
        [self.contentView addSubview:hundred];
        [self.contentView addSubview:fourTwo];
        [self.contentView addSubview:twoOne];
        [self.contentView addSubview:itemNo];
        [self.contentView addSubview:itemName];
        [self.contentView addSubview:itemDesc];
        [self.contentView addSubview:department];
        [self.contentView addSubview:qtyAvailable];
        [self.contentView addSubview:check];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;

    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

    CGRect frame;

    frame=CGRectMake(boundsX+10, 0, 50, 40);

    sNO.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+70 ,0, 150, 40);

    abcWine.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+230 ,0, 150, 40);

    redWine.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+390 ,0, 50, 40);

    two.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+450 ,0, 50, 40);

    hundred.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+510 ,0, 50, 40);

    fourTwo.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+570 ,0, 50, 40);

    twoOne.frame = frame;

    /************************                      ***********************/

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+10 ,50, 100, 200);

    imgView.frame = frame;


}

-(void) clicked
{

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Just ust the instance of this class in cellforRowAtIndexPath and also modify it according to your needs.To change the values at runtime acces the properties.

You can implement the custom cemm in tableview this way :-

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomizedCellProductDetails *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomizedCellProductDetails alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.sNO.text=@"2255";
    cell.abcWine.text=@"ABCWine";
    cell.redWine.text=@"REDWine";
    cell.two.text=@"2";
    cell.hundred.text=@"100";
    cell.fourTwo.text=@"42";
    cell.twoOne.text=@"21";

    [cell.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wine.png"]];
    cell.itemNo.text=@"Item No                     2255";
    cell.itemName.text=@"Item Name                 ABCWine";
    cell.itemDesc.text=@"Item Description          This is the best wine";
    cell.qtyAvailable.text=@"Quantity Available    2";
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

change the height of cell:-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {  

        return 300;  


}
```

dont use 300 instead give it the height of frame of cell as `cell.frame.size.height`

Comment: xorro: thanks for the reply, i tried aS YOU SAID.this is how i create instance.CustomizedCellProductDetails *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomizedCellProductDetails alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
i get some issues. pls let me know how to do

Comment: i get this warning : incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct UITableViewCell *', expected 'struct CustomizedCellProductDetails *'. pls let me know

Comment: tupecast it ..(CustomizedCellProductDetails  *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; ..

Comment: also when tapping the cell, i was not able to edit it and the cursor is not shown .pls let me know

Comment: you have to do it didselectrowatindexpath re [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10602224/936588)which i have done

Comment: Nothing in this cell is user editable - all the text is in labels. This is not a useful answer.

Comment: Hi if you want the user to enter text just say re ...in uitableview editable may mean edit/delete also...replace UILabel with UItextField.

Comment: ok, in did select row do i need to add uitextfield?yes i want the user to be editable? pls let me know. sorry to be dumb question

Comment: @jrurton...See loc ..its Q&A forum ..not tutorial forum ..gave enough logic to have it implemented ..created a custom class..what else.editable may have different meaning such as editing the contents of cell's subviews...editing apple's way....(copy , paste , delete etc setEditing of UITableView may also have been used in that sense)..He must have written user-inputs if that's what is editing.

Comment: You add uitextfield in customcell man replace the uilabel code with uitextfield that's all..didselectrow is for editing the contents and attributes..I think u shud [see this tutorial](http://jainmarket.blogspot.in/2009/05/creating-custom-table-view-cell.html)