# Why can't I set an image to my UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created an option menu using a `UITableViewController` and can get the labels to set correctly, but not the images.

I tried taking out the switch statement and using an array filled with the correct values based on `[indexPath row]` and could not get it to work correctly either.

Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    switch ([indexPath row]) {
        case 0:
            [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"42-photos.png"]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Photos"];
            break;
        case 1:
            [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"280-clapboard.png"]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Videos"];
            break;
        case 2:
            [[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"42-info.png"]];
            [[cell textLabel] setText:@"About"];
            break;
        default:
            return cell;
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more: Do the images exist? Are they added to the build bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` doesn't include the image:

> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with text
>   that is right-aligned and blue; on the right side of the cell is
>   another label with smaller text that is left-aligned and black. The
>   Phone/Contacts application uses cells in this style.

You should use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` instead (or design your own cell).

Comment: I totally forgot that I changed that while trying out other things. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have not created a custom cell i guess , it's better to have a custom cell if you have so many controls in your UITableViewCell and then accessing the property to the controls you can change the image.you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10602224/936588) of mine.Your style chosen will not support image.